How to know what is keeping shopify post purchase page being placed?
This is the shop I am working in it, and it's a live store. Everything looks fine except for /post-purchase route is not showing up. If the render returns true Shopify will render the page. But, it has also some limitations. Order must be at least worth of $0.50 or more, which I fulfilled. You also have to have a shipping address (physical product), these criteria are also met. I also paid in USD. Shipping requires $25 USD, so I had to use discount. Also, I had to reduce the product price to $0.50 using discount. Is the discount preventing me from having the post-purchase page?
